# Using std::thread to call functions from two Classes in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11, stdthread

I am trying to implement an API that should let the user create two communication channels in parallel. One channel uses TCP and the other uses UDP. I have two classes representing the two channels. These classes have different functions implemented. I would like the functions from the two channels to run in parallel. For that I am using `std::thread` to create two threads, one for each channel (class). 
The idea is the following following 
The header file looks like

```
class Channel_1
{
public:
     int myfunc(int a, int b);
};

class Channel_2
{
public:
    int anotherfunc(int a, int b);
};
```

In the main cpp file 
include the header file

```
int main()
{
  int a = 10, b = 20;
  Channel_1 ch1;
  Channel_2 ch2;

  std::thread t(ch1.myfunc, a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the error saying that no instance of the constructor `std::thread` exists.

I have the following questions.

1. Can't we call the functions from a class in the thread
   constructor?
2. Does this idea of using threads for calling functions from different classes make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems:

1. The syntax is wrong. You need to pass a pointer to the member function, as in

   ```
   std::thread t(&Channel_1::myfunc, a, b);
   ```
2. Non-static member functions needs to be called on an instance of the class. This instance must be passed as the first argument:

   ```
   std::thread t(&Channel_1::myfunc, ch1, a, b);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As *Some programmer dude* said, you need to supply a pointer to the function (either a static or non-static). A third option could be to make a base class that implements a `start()` method that uses this thread constructor:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

Example using a lambda. It's not meant to be a complete working example, It's only meant to show how the third thread constructor *could* be used.

```
class thread_base {
private:
    std::thread m_th;
    bool m_terminated;

    void proxy() {
        // in the new thread
        // add thread_base setup here if needed and
        // call the execute() method in the derived class
        execute();
    }
public:
    thread_base() : m_th(), m_terminated(false) {}
    thread_base(const thread_base&) = delete;
    thread_base& operator=(const thread_base&) = delete;
    thread_base(thread_base&&) = default;
    thread_base& operator=(thread_base&&) = default;
    virtual ~thread_base() { join(); }

    virtual void start() {
        if(joinable()) throw std::runtime_error("thread already running");
        else m_th = std::thread( [this] { proxy(); } );
    }

    inline bool joinable() { return m_th.joinable(); }
    inline void join() { if(joinable()) { m_th.join(); m_terminated=false; } }
    inline void terminate() { m_terminated=true; }
    inline bool terminated() { return m_terminated; }

    virtual void execute() = 0; // implement this in your derived classes
};


class Channel_1 : public thread_base {
    void execute() {
        // runs in a thread
        // with a volontary check if a soft termination
        // request has been issued
        while( !terminated() ) {
            // work
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: A virtual final member in the base class?

Comment: Yeah, it should be public and not possible to override. This was the first I thought of but perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: Is the downvote for the `virtual final` member or something else?

Comment: For virtual final method in base, for immediate core dump due to destructor of temporary `std::thread` called on non-joined thread, for unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Ok, it was not a complete working base class, but rather something to show how the third thread constructor could be used. I added a little more boilerplate (still not a complete base class though). As for the `virtual final` method, I don't know of another way of preventing it from being overridden.

Comment: Removed `final` and made the base class working. Definitely more code than I intended just to show one use of the third constructor, but it could perhaps come in handy for someone.